# AngularJS use trustAsHtml function to allow only part of the string

Tags: angularjs

I have the next notification data stored in the DB:

**Someone** has done something with your post, just now.

Now, I want the someone to be displayed as bold and in order to do that I have to use trustAsHtml, but what if the username is like this:

**alert('xss');**

and therefore the output will become:

alert('xss'); has done something with your post, just now.

With the trustAsHtml function there is a xss attack.
How to avoid this with AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$sanitize service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize):

> Sanitizes an html string by stripping all potentially dangerous tokens.

`<script>` goes away and `<b>` stays:

```js
angular
  .module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('Ctrl', function(){
    var model = this;
    
    model.message = "<b>name<script>alert('xss')</"+"script></b> has done something with your post, just now.";
    
    return model;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
  <span ng-bind-html="ctrl.message"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay got it. When using the dependency, the ng-bind will anyway escapes everything, ng-bind-html will sanitize only for white label, and ng-bind-html with a $sce.trustAsHtml method will allow any danger html without any escaping.

So it will be smart injecting the $ngSanitize module dependency and using ng-bind-html in case I want to allow such a case described above.

Thank you very much!